# Phonegap unable Archive by this error "Command / usr / sbin / chown failed with exit code 1"

Tags: cordova

I use Xcode 4.5.1 and use the latest installation package PhoneGap "2.1.0"
I installed the following:

1. Create one new folder name PhoneGapApp.
2. Copy two folders: "bin" and "CordovaLib" directory PhoneGapApp was made ​​available.
3. Running Terminal:

   - Chmod-R 777 for all Folder "PhoneGapApp".
   - Move the folder "bin" using the cd command.
   - Run the "Create" in the bin directory to create a new application named: newappphonegap
4. Open the New Project in Xcode -> select Device and conduct Archive.
   After running the application the following error message:

> SetOwnerAndGroup "NGUYEN:staff" /Users/NGUYEN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/phonegap-bbxcrooiwxhhpkbtvbseflkcjksr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/CordovaLib/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/libCordova.a
>       cd "/Volumes/MacBook Pro Data/phonegapapp/CordovaLib"
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /usr/sbin/chown -RH "NGUYEN:staff" /Users/NGUYEN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/phonegap-bbxcrooiwxhhpkbtvbseflkcjksr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/CordovaLib/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/libCordova.a
>
> chown: /Users/NGUYEN/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/phonegap-bbxcrooiwxhhpkbtvbseflkcjksr/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/CordovaLib/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/UninstalledProducts/libCordova.a: No such file or directory
>   Command /usr/sbin/chown failed with exit code 1

I Remove ARMv6 Project and Cordova, but still getting this error, I also tried to find this error on the internet and follow but almost no results.

Who can help me.
thank you!

Answer (score 8):

What I found out and tried is the following:

- Under the Build Settings of the project set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `YES`.

You might want to set CordovaLib.xcodeproj under the Project Navigation icon showing the list of files to YES as well.

Comment: Of all the suggestions out there this is the only one that worked!

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by doing BOTH things cereallarceny said

1. Under the Build Settings of the project set **Build Active Architecture Only** to YES.
2. Under the Build Settings of the project for CordovaLib.xcodeproj (have to choose all options) set **Build Active Architecture Only** to YES

Answer (score 0):

I actually got this error to go away by disconnecting a device from the macbook where I was running my XCode. Once there was no device attached everything compiled and linked without errors. With the device attached I was always getting this stupid SetOwnerAndGroup error...

Answer (score 0):

I recently got this error as well. Closing and relaunching XCode fixed it for me.